# python how to access input params in MagicMock?

Tags: python, mocking

I want to add a unit test for the function 'method_a':

```
def method_a(some_thing):
    #some logic here
    return update({'a':1}, request=some_thing)

def update(value, request):
    if request:
      return value.update({'b':2})
    return value.update({'c':3})
```

Actually I don't care the logic of update method. All I want to do is to use MagicMock or whatever tools to mock update method, and let it return the first paramater of it received (In this case, should return {'a': 1}). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `patch` function. Here's an example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch


def method_a(some_thing):
    #some logic here
    return update({'a': 1}, request=some_thing)


def update(value, request):
    if request:
        return value.update({'b': 2})
    return value.update({'c': 3})


class TestMethodA(TestCase):
    def test_mocked_update(self):
        with patch('%s.update' % __name__, lambda value, request: value):
            self.assertEqual(method_a('test'), {'a': 1})
```

Hope that helps.